# libcurl: unable to download and write whole file to disk

Tags: c, libcurl

I'm trying to dinamically download a [json file](https://ref.gs1.org/standards/epcis/2.0.0/epcis-context.jsonld) using libcurl in C, based on [this example](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html) from the official documentation.
Here is my code

```
int main() {
    FILE *json_ctx_file = NULL;
    /* code */
    CURL *curl = NULL;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    
    if (curl == NULL) {
        printf("Error initializing curl, trying to fallback to a cached context file\n");
        goto ctx_file;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ctx_url_string);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    json_ctx_file = fopen(ctx_file_name, "wb+");
    if (json_ctx_file != NULL) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, json_ctx_file);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
    } else {
        printf("Error opening file, trying to fallback to a cached version\n");
        goto ctx_file;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    fclose(json_ctx_file);
    /* code */
}
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
    return written;
}
```

The file is correctly written to the disk but stops abruptly always on the same line (line 582, near *"queryName"* if you look at the original file).
I suspect there is a memory management problem somewhere, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Fwiw, I tested your program and it downloaded the whole file for me.

Comment: The line after `queryName` is exactly 20480 bytes into the file. That looks like a multiple of a likely power-of-2 buffer size, which seems very suspicious.

Comment: The symptom seems like the result of not flushing the output buffer, but this should happen automatically in `fclose()`.

Comment: Your code includes `goto ctx_file` a few times but where's the `ctx_file` label?

Comment: @TedLyngmo to be honest, it worked for me a coupe of times, but deleting and trying to download the file again for testing purposes gave me that error.

Comment: @Barmar I manually set the option `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 1048576);` (aka 1MB) and now *it seems* to work. tomorrow I'll test more

Comment: @Shawn is a part of the code where i try to read and parse the file, it doesn't work with this poorly downladed file, but if I manualy download and savethe file it works fine, so it's not a problem

Comment: You're not checking any return values from `libcurl`.  From the code you've posted, you don't know what HTTP response code you received from the server.  You also don't know if `curl_easy_perform()` returned success or not.

Comment: If you run it on Windows, you get troubles.

Comment: @273K on Windows the app crashes on startup, but since my target is a Unix system, I didn't care much. Just for personal knowledge, what is the problem here?

Comment: The crashes on Windows are describe in the [manual](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html)